# How can we pass any value (selected one) from dialog to activity in android?

Tags: android, dialog

I need help to pass values from a custom dialog to an activity.
I cannot understand what should i use. I already used intent, but dialog doesn't support intent value passing . 
So anyone can help me here, i am totally stucked.If you have any basic example for it, then that will be excellent.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried using a variable to store that value and pass that value to a method at d time of dialog dismiss,within that dialog you can use intent..

Comment: please can you put your erronous code here??

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from the Google Documentation:

```
// Alert Dialog code (mostly copied from the Android docs
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        myFunction(item);
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

// Now elsewhere in your Activity class, you would have this function
private void myFunction(int result){
    // Now the data has been "returned" (as pointed out, that's not
    // the right terminology)
}
```